# 500 error on product duplicate

Tags: magento2, product, http-error-500, duplicate

We are facing issues with Product Duplicate. When we are trying to duplicate the product it gives 500 errors.

**Internal Server Error**

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Here is server log:

```
[Wed Mar 18 05:46:06.257548 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 13816] [client 000.000.000.00:00000] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 101 seconds, referer: https://magento224/admin/catalog/product/edit/id/168/key/8874a4dcfb2a19f3c01f7dbb711c44bc1533c3e980bd5d343709973781e7afc7/

[Wed Mar 18 05:46:06.257695 2020] [core:error] [pid 13816] [client 000.000.000.00:00000] End of script output before headers: index.php, referer: https://magento224/admin/catalog/product/edit/id/168/key/8874a4dcfb2a19f3c01f7dbb711c44bc1533c3e980bd5d343709973781e7afc7/
```